# Not getting the given answer while computing std deviation of a binomial distribution

Tags: probability

I am trying to find the mean and standard deviation of a binomial distribution.
A basket ball player has the following probability for success in two shot free throws.
P(0) is 0.16, 
P(1) is 0.48
P (2) is 0.36

I need to find the mean and std deviation.
I get the mean correctly as 1.2, but not able to get the std. deviation of the given answer of 0.69. Requesting guidance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability / statistics / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

[Standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) equation:

```
std_dev = sqrt(sum((x_i - mean) ^ 2 * p_i))
```

So, your example:

```
std_dev = sqrt((0 - 1.2)^2 * 0.16 + (1 - 1.2)^2 * 0.48 + (2 - 1.2)^2 * 0.36)
        = sqrt(1.44 * 0.16 + 0.04 * 0.48 + 0.64 * 0.36)
        = sqrt(0.2304 + 0.0192 + 0.2304)
        = sqrt(0.48)
       ~= 0.69282
```